# Hidden Fields are not storing certain values in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

In my ASP.NET MVC view I have the following hidden variables.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedAmount)
```

Which I was able to display in the page using,

```
@Model.TotalAmount
```

I used AJAX to get these hidden fields as below. 
`$("#TotalAmount").val()` and `$("#SelectedAmount").val()`.
**TotalAmount** is always 0 and I am getting **SelectedAmount** correctly.

Please help me to find what wrong with this.

Update:

From developers tool I see :

However I am getting the value of Model.TotalAmount printed in the page using @String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", @Model.TotalAmount)

Comment: What is the output html when the view is rendered for your given model? Does TotalAmount have a value in the html?

Comment: Yes it shows correct value when I say Model.TotalAmount

Comment: Look at the HTML source and see if the hidden field is being render correctly

Comment: Are you rendering Total Amount more than one time?

Comment: Is there any script that might be updating the element $("#TotalAmount")?

Comment: Oky may be I should be little more clearer, okay when I examine all the hidden values which are missing their actual values are the ones which I manually added to an already existing Model. That is I already get a post to one particular action from another view which has certain values for that model, In that controller I am manually adding the missing one. Will that info helps?

Comment: @JustinHarvey Sorry there are none I can find..

Comment: @RaoEhsan No it is only one time and this is the code : @String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", @Model.TotalAmount)

Comment: Don't look in just the controller, the issue may be the javascript which is run in the browser. The JS is trying to select the value out of the DOM, which is constructed based on the HTML returned when the view is rendered. So, if you are in an Action with an empty value of TotalAmount, check what's posted in the request, if it's empty in the request, check the DOM when you are building the request, if it's empty in the DOM, check the value in the response returned from the first action, if it's empty in the response, check the view, then the controller. Find the right point in that chain.

Comment: Oky If i see using the developer tool that value is 0. But I am worried more now because @String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", @Model.TotalAmount) showing correct value in that page. and @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TotalAmount) not working

Comment: Try this one
<input type="hidden" id="TotalAmount" name="TotalAmount" value="@Model.TotalAmount">

What is the data type of total amount?

Comment: The Issue I have solved by using TEMPDATA to store the values. However I am not sure why the above did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just print the value to your script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var totalAmount = @Model.TotalAmount;       
    }   
</script>
```

Ofcourse you still need the hidden fields if you want to keep the values in your model in submit.

This is just one solution to your problem.

Comment: Or just use the developer tools to inspect the value of the hidden field

Comment: Ok If I manually pass @Model.TotalAmount to that Ajax field it takes it.

Comment: @erikkallen that value is zero in hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
this will help you for the same purpose

```
<input type="hidden" name="Step" value="@Model.TotalAmount" />
```